# The sign of pure jump Levy process

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is a probability space. Assume $(X_{t}, P)$ is a Levy process with generating triplet $( 0, 0, \nu)$ with $X_{0}=0$. This means there is no continuous part in $X_{t}$.  My question,  what kinds of condition on the Levy measure $\nu$ can lead to the following identity: for any $s>0$,

$  P(\omega: X_{s-}(\omega)=0)=0 $.

My guess is that $\nu$ is absolute continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure on real line and with non-zero radon-nikodym density.  This question is related to (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159811/the-probability-of-levy-process-staying-at-a-point)

Any reference is appreciated.